# first website, need assistance with certain click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two tabs on this option. I have already created a mouseover and mouseleave for these two tabs. When you highlight one or the other, they share a background color.

However, now I am creating a click function. When you click on one of these tabs, I would like for it to maintain that background color, and even if the user highlighted the second time, it would not change color this time. Reason I want to do this is to show which tab is active, because each will have its own seperate content which will appear will clicked within the same div.

HTML code:

```
<div class="meal-details">
  <h4>Lobster & Summer Vegetables with Spicy Herbed Butter</h4>
  <h5 class="optiontabs meal-description">DESCRIPTION</h5>
  <h5 class="optiontabs nutrition-description">NUTRITIONAL INFO</h5>
  <div class="nutrition-breakdown">
    <p>This is the nutrition info bro</p>
  </div>
  <div class="meal-breakdown">
    <p>The meal breakdown and descrition.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".optiontabs").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#3e597c");

  });

  $(".optiontabs").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#141C25");

  });

  $(".nutrition-description").click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#3e597c");
    $(this).nextAll(".nutrition-breakdown").css("display", "initial");
    $(this).nextAll(".meal-breakdown").css("display", "none");
  });

});
```

My question is, what is the best method to use in order to achieve what I have mentioned above. I have asked Jquery to change the background-color of the active tab but its not doing it. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unbind the mouseover and mouseleave once you click on an element once. You can do that using the `$('element').off('event')` syntax. Please look at the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var countClick = 0;

    if(countClick==0) {
        $(".optiontabs").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#3e597c");
      });

      $(".optiontabs").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#141C25");
      });
    }

    $(".nutrition-description").click(function() {
        $(".optiontabs").off("mouseleave");
        $(".optiontabs").off("mouseover");
        countClick++;
        $(this).css("background-color", "#3e597c");
        $(this).nextAll(".nutrition-breakdown").css("display", "initial");
        $(this).nextAll(".meal-breakdown").css("display", "none");
    });

});
```